# How to convert .jar file to windows service

Tags: java, windows, rest, web-services, jar

I have developed a web service( REST API ) as Java Application(Java version: 1.8) and now I want to convert jar file to exe file and should run as windows service.

I have converted the jar file into setup file to install and I want to run the setup file at specific intervals.

I tried above problem in cmd

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create "DataTransfer" binpath= "D:\web service\webservice.exe" start= auto
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

C:\Windows\system32>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DataTransfer\Parameters" /v Application /d "D:\web service\webservice.exe"
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>sc start "DataTransfer"
```

but Error:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Please share any solution ...

Answer (score 1):

A jar script need JVM and all the environement in JRE to execute so you can't convert your .jar to a .exe easly

But I think you have two option anyway, the first is to inclute JRE in you .exe file in a kind of Zip, but it will be an heavy file

And the second in to try searching about the .JNLP file, which I think use the java environement by the web. Maybe more what you're trying to do.

Comment: I converted the jar file to exe by Launch4j application